# How can I serialize an element that has been dynamically loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What happens is that I have a list of tags that needs to be refreshed using an ajax call.

I clean the `<ul>` containing the tags.
With the ajax response I populate the `<ul>` with `<li>`'s of tags appending them with `.append()`
In my browser everything shows as expected, the new tags are there.
Then I click a save button and call a series of functions and beetwen those functions I try to make a `serializeArray()` with the new tags but it doesn't work.

The logic for all of this is alright, since it works with the default tags, only when the tags get's refreshed with jQuery I cannot perform this operations.
I already checked that the refreshed tags have the same format as the default tags.

Please, help.
Just one thing I cannot install more plugins.
My version of jQuery is 1.4.2
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure your DOM looks exactly the same (only with different text nodes) before and after the AJAX call, also check to see the console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that after refreshing tags dynamically, the events such as click are not performed or not working than you will have to use `.live()` in handling events.  For eg,

```
$("li").live("click",function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.serializeArray()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) applies to form elements.

Are you sure you are recreating those as well ? (*they might be hidden and located outside of the `<ul>` structure*)

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM updates, that so You need to rebind actions after ajax loading. You can use `.live()` function to automaticly rebind actions, also You can use `.bind()` in callback of ajax.